# Rails - on click event - how to deal with race condition between 2 Ruby methods?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

On my view I have a `link_to` element "Start Quiz!" that calls a controller method (method A) that sets a variable "Phase" and redirects the user to a new static page. In my CoffeeScript I have an event listener listening for clicks on this `link_to` element. The listener calls a different method (method B) on the backend that uses the "Phase" variable to do sth.

The problem: sometimes method B tries to use the "Phase" variable before it has been updated by the controller method A! Does anyone have a suggestion what the best way would be to ensure that the "Phase" variable was updated before using it for anything else?

I'm a Rails beginner and would appreciate any pointers. :)

---

EDIT:
"Phase" is a variable I use to track the current question of my quiz. It's not dependent on any input, but it needs increment whenever a new page is rendered (which is triggered by the button click).

---

EDIT2:
I've now tried to solve this by introducing an instance variable flag "is_changed" to my controller and letting the method B sleep until the flag is set to true:

```
#method B:
def send_answers
   until controller.index_changed?
     sleep(0.5)
   end
   ...
   do sth.
end

#method A (in controller):
def initialize
   @index_changed = false
end

def index_changed?
   @index_changed
end

def set_index_changed!
   @index_changed = false
end

def switch_to_next_question
   ...
   self.phase += 1
   if self.save
      Thread.new do
         @index_changed = true
         ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close
      end
   else
      ...
   end
end
```

It's not working. Method A gets stuck sleeping. How do I fix this? And is this even the right approach?

Is it a problem with the scope of my @index_changed variable? I'm trying to create an instance variable that is accessible from multiple methods within the class, but individual to each instance of this class.

Comment: What are you setting the variable 'Phase' to? Can it be explicitly set at render time?

Comment: you just need to understand the difference between javascript and ruby events. The Javascript event handler will happen first and only take place on the browser. It's only after a HTTP request to the server is made that the ruby event happens - actually rails does not care whether or not it was a click or hover or what as long as it receives a http request.

Comment: Precisely @maxpleaner. If you want the event listener to capture that information, you need to make sure you can set the data in your controller backend, to render in the view (you can't just pass data to your browser it has to go through the view). To do this, you basically need to output the data to make sure your html view can output the required information.

Comment: @max : Yes, that makes sense. But the method that my CoffeeScript calls is actually on the server side (ActionCable corresponding `channel.rb`). Since that Button press is the only thing that triggers a new "phase" (@Cyzanfar : I'm building a quiz app, so phase 1 - display question, phase 2 - display results etc.) I'm specifically looking for a way to avoid race conditions between the 2 methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it by finding a way to call the 2 methods sequentially. I ended up eliminating the on click listener completely and **calling the ActionCable backend method directly**, which was possible by turning it into a class method:

```
class QuizDataChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  #method B:
  def self.send_answers #self. makes it a class method
    #...
    #do something with phase
  end
end
```

And in my controller:

```
#method A:
def switch_to_next_question
   #...
   self.phase += 1
   if self.save
      QuizDataChannel.send_answers
   else
      #...
   end
end
```

As you can see in the end I got rid of all of these: `sleep`, new threads and the `index_changed` flag.